# How can I iterate on both rows and cols of a sparse matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matlab, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

how can I iterate on both rows and cols of a sparse matrix in Eigen?

I've a row major sparse matrix which I want to do these matlab commands on it:

> r=sum(H,1)
>
> r2=sum(H,2)

where H is sparse matrix (of 0,1), r and r2 are integer vectors .  I think that I must be able to do both iteration on row and col to do it. any suggestion will be appreciated .

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `H(p==1,2)`? Du you mean that p ==1 or p==2?

Comment: @kkuilla excuse me , I've a mistake. I edited it. when we write sum(H,2) it returns a vector containing sum of each row at indices , and for sum|(H,1) returns sum of each column.

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand... What is the question? Are you saying that you want to take the sum of the entire matrix and get a single value in return?

Comment: @kkuilla , I want to take a vector which it's elements are sum of each cols(resp. rows) ,  so for each of them , the command returns a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the very useful `eigen` / `matlab` conversion reference:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt

In your case it translates to:

```
r  = H.colwise().sum() // sum(H, 1)
r2 = H.rowwise().sum() // sum(H, 2)
```

**EDIT**

As you pointed out, sparse matrices do not support these functions. You probably have to re-implement it. I suggest to get insparation from https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=122971

In your example of `sum(H, 1)`, it can be written as:

```
r = H * VectorXd::Ones(H.cols())
```

Comment: sparseMatrix class hasn't any member colwise() or rowwise().

Comment: when I write "VectorXd::Ones" says that VectorXd hasn't Ones.?!!

Comment: It should be part of Eigne::VectorXd following http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ad148f93a6a00e32ef00903c5393337ef . Try to reproduce their example.